# Using SXA's "Gallery" component to view all images under "media library" automatically

Tags: sxa, media-library

I am Using `SXA 1.6`, my question is about the gallery component.

I need the gallery component to be able to view all the images under `media library`, and not be restricted to a component of type `gallery` and a specified set of `gallery image` under it only, i.e. I need the gallery component to view all items of type `Image` automatically. how can I achieve that?

Alternatively, is there a way for me to set the data source of the gallery component to be the media library folder? so that it would automatically read all the `Image` items under it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to have to customize the Gallery component for that. I think you are missing how the components work.

The DataSource for a Gallery is a `Gallery Folder` template. You can't just set it to look at media items. You can only set a single DataSource for a component. Once you have set the Gallery component DataSource, then you can add `Gallery` items which link through to media items.

From your requirements, you would need to create a custom component to do that. You might start by cloning the `Gallery` component and then implementing your own code, change the DataSource template definition and modify the view to meet your requirements. But the out of the box `Gallery` component will not support going direct to the images.